# Ignore error message of error-handling?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal, uninstallation, pascalscript

How I could ignore the error msgbox if the **uninstall.vsf** file does not exists when calling `LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall` function in this code?

I supposed that using a **Try** block with an empty **Except** will be enough as in other languages, but this is not the case.

```
// Import the LoadVCLStyle function from VclStylesInno.DLL
procedure LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(VClStyleFile: String); external 'LoadVCLStyleA@{app}\uninstall.dll stdcall uninstallonly';

//E: Occurs when the uninstaller initializes.
function InitializeUninstall: Boolean;
begin

  Result := True;

  // Initialize the VCL skin style.
  try
    LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(ExpandConstant('{app}\uninstall.vsf'));
  except 
  finally
  end;

end;
```

[image]

Comment: What you see is not an exception, but a message box [`shown by`](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-plugins/source/browse/trunk/InnoSetup%20plugin/VclStylesInno.dpr#61) that plugin when an exception is raised. This case you can workaround by checking if the `FileExists` before you attempt to load the skin; with any other exception you're quite out of luck. DLLs must not raise any exception, but should not show any dialogs when they encounter some, IMHO. A `GetLastError` like system would be better there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possibility to check for the file existence beforehand was already mentioned.

*The user TLama mentioned that the code in the question is not regular pascal program code, but Inno Setup script code and and that my answer doesn't apply in this case. Because the following text could be of interest for pascal programmers we keep it.*

The `EXCEPT` statement by itself doesn't handle the exception, it marks only the point where program execution should continue after an error has occured. When the exception isn't handled/caught in the `EXCEPT ... END` block it will be transferd to the next higher `EXCEPT` statement. (Freepacal reference guide chapter 17)

I also don't think that `TRY ... EXCEPT ... FINALLY ... END` will work. Either `EXCEPT` or `FINALLY`, not both.

If you want to capture the exception you must do something like:

```
TRY
  LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(ExpandConstant('{app}\uninstall.vsf'));
EXCEPT 
  On EWhateverException DO ...;
END;
```

If the exception class for this error isn't defined in the documentation, you can use the following trick to find the exception class name:

```
TRY
  LoadVCLStyle_UnInstall(ExpandConstant('{app}\uninstall.vsf'));
EXCEPT 
  ON Exception DO WriteLn(ExceptObject.ClassName);
END;
```

With `ON Exception DO ..` you can catch any exception, but i don't recomend to use that variant for the definite program.

Comment: This is wrong. You were probably thinking of a construction like `on E: ExceptionClass do` where `E` is the variable that will get acquired the exception object in the `except` block. Well, none of this will work in Inno Setup Pascal Script. Moreover, that will not resolve the problem with that plugin (which is just showing the message box; it's not an exception raised in the setup).

Comment: @TLama - Then why is TRY ... EXCEPT supported?

Comment: The fact that exception classes, nor `on` constructs are not supported doesn't mean that it's meaningless to have `try..except` blocks. You don't have to filter on certain exception classes in `except` blocks (that's optional). Finally, exception handling in the OP's script has nothing to do with the message box that is shown in the question. Answer to this question is that the message box is displayed by that plugin when an exception is raised inside it; no `try..except` block will prevent it from being shown. It's hardcoded in that plugin.

Comment: Really I've solved this issue using FileExists function as @TLama suggested me, I recognize that I don't tested this solution because I contacted the author of the plugin and he seems to have solved/changed the error-hnadlings. But thanks both guys I just marked the answer as accepted to give you some points for your help :). bye